# Show that $\sigma$ induces a permutation of the set of all zeros of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ that are in $E$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $E$ be an algebraic extension of a field $F$ , and let $\sigma$ be an automorphism of $E$ leaving $F$ fixed. Let $\alpha\in E$. I'm trying to show that $\sigma$ induces a permutation of the set of all zeros of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ that are in $E$. I have no idea. Anyone can help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$, and write
$$f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_0$$
Since the $a_i$ are in $F$ (and are therefore fixed by $\sigma$), it follows that
$$ 0=\sigma(f(\alpha))=\sigma(\alpha)^n+a_{n-1}\sigma(\alpha)^{n-1}+\dots+a_0=f(\sigma(\alpha)) $$
hence $\sigma(\alpha)$ is another root of $f$. Therefore $\sigma$ maps roots of $f$ to roots of $f$, and this map must be a permutation because $\sigma$ is invertible.